# Creating Two Distributions Each with Different Sections Colored Differently

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw in `R` a figure similar to this one generated by G*Power:

[image: G*Power Distributions Showing Errors of Types 1 & 2]

in which the left-hand distribution, `H0`, is colored red when `H0 >= 2` and where the right-hand distribution is colored blue, when `H1 < 2`.

With data generated via:

```
install.packages("bayestestR")
mean1 <- 0
sd1 <- 1
data1 <- bayestestR::rnorm_perfect(n = 1000, mean1, sd1)

df.data1 <- data.frame(x = data1) %>% mutate(y = dnorm(x))
df.data1$dist <- "H0"

mean2 <- 2.5
sd2 <- 1
data2 <- bayestestR::rnorm_perfect(n = 1000, mean2, sd2)

df.data2 <- data.frame(x = data2) %>% mutate(y = dnorm(x))
df.data2$dist <- "H1"

df.both <- rbind(df.data1, df.data2)
```

The following code can produce the first goal:

```
ggplot(df.both, aes(x = x, fill = dist)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(df.both, dist == "H0"), aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ifelse(x >= 2, y, 0)), fill = "pink", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(df.both, dist == "H0"), aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ifelse(x >= 2, y, 0)), fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "x", fill = "Distribution") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("H0" = "pink", "H1" = "lightblue")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Figure Showing H0 Red When SD >= 2]

But the closest I can get to the second is via:

```
ggplot(df.both, aes(x = x, fill = dist)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(df.both, dist == "H1"), aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ifelse(x <= 2, y, 0)), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(df.both, dist == "H1"), aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ifelse(x <= 2, y, 0)), fill = "lightblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "x", fill = "Distribution") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("H0" = "pink", "H1" = "lightblue")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: One of Many Failed Attempts to Correctly Color H1 When It's < 2]

Where, incorrectly, the right-hand `H1` is not colored blue outside of its overlap with the left-hand `H0`, but where `H0` is incorrectly colored blue in that same ribbon.

I don't need to use `ggplot2` (heck, I'll take crayons and napkins at this point)---just something clear and reproducible. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927636/fill-multiple-areas-under-normal-probability-curve) use of `ggplot::stat_function` looks promising, but I've been unable to figure how to create an other normal distribution with it at an other location (e.g., where mean = 2.5).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wnat package are you using to get `rnorm_perfect` ?

Comment: It's part of the bayestestR (easystats.github.io/bayestestR) package. I've modified the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stat_function`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(X=c(-3,6)), aes(x=X)) + 
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x,0, 1), col='red')+ 
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 0, 1)*(.x >= 2), fill='red', 
                geom = 'polygon', n=1000, alpha = 0.5)+ 
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x,2.5, 1), col='blue')+
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 2.5, 1)*(.x < 2), fill='blue',
                geom = 'polygon', alpha=0.4, n = 1000)
```

[image]

---

Using `geom_function` + `geom_polygon`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(X=c(-3,6)), aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x,0, 1), col='red')+
  geom_polygon(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 0, 1)*(.x >= 2), fill='red',
               stat = 'function',n=1000, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x,2.5, 1), col='blue') +
  geom_polygon(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 2.5, 1)*(.x < 2), fill='blue',
               stat = 'function', alpha=0.4, n = 1000)
```

[image]

---

Note that you could use `polygon` alone. `ggplot` fuctions are quite related. One can solve the same problem in multiple ways

```
ggplot(data.frame(X=c(-3,6)), aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_polygon(fun = ~dnorm(.x,0, 1), col='red',
               stat = 'function', fill = 'grey93')+
  geom_polygon(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 0, 1)*(.x >= 2), fill='red',
               stat = 'function',n=1000, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_polygon(fun = ~dnorm(.x,2.5, 1), col='red',
               stat = 'function', fill = 'grey93')+
  geom_polygon(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 2.5, 1)*(.x < 2), fill='blue',
               stat = 'function', alpha=0.4, n = 1000)
```

Comment: Not only an elegant solution, but three of them!

Comment: @wes it boils down to a matter of taste. Others prefer specifying `geom` in `stat` while others prefer specifying `stat` in `geom`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start using `stat_function`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(X=c(-3,6)), aes(x=X)) +
  stat_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x, 0, 1), aes(fill = "H[0]"), geom = "area", alpha = 0.5) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x-2.5, 0, 1), aes(fill = "H[1]"), geom = "area", alpha = 0.5) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {y <- dnorm(x, 0, 1); y[x < 2] <- 0; y;}, aes(fill = "quux"), geom = "area")
```

[image]

Specific colors and labels notwithstanding.

The use of the initial `data.frame(X=c(-3,6))` is mostly used to define the domain (range of x) of the plot.

Comment: Thank you. The coloring of `H1` below x = 2 is oddly perplexing

Comment: due to `alpha=` in both PDFs, translucent-red and translucent-green gives a slightly darker shade. You can remove the alpha if you prefer opacity.